# If $f(x) = \int_{a}^{x}(x-t)g(t) \, dt$, does $f'(x) = (x-x)g(x) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $g$ be continuous on $[a,b]$, and let $f(x) = \int_{a}^{x}(x-t)g(t) \, dt$. Prove that $f$ is a solution of the
> differential equation $f'' = g$ and the initial conditions $f(a) = f'(a) = 0$.

I remember in Calc 1 that I just plugged in $x$ for $t$; if the upper limit of integration was not $x$ - e.g. $x^2$ - then we used the chain rule. Is $f'(x) = 0$?

Comment: Did you try to compute $f(x+h)-f(x)$ to see what the quotient by $h$ will look like? If $g(t) = 1$ then $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2$, so certainly $f'$ is not zero.

Comment: You are not remembering that you were only allowed to do that when the integrand was independent  of $x$. Here there's a second term to be added, $\int_a^x \frac{d}{dx}[(x-t)g(t)]dt$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write

$$f(x) = \int_{a}^{x}(x-t)g(t) \, dt= x\int_{a}^{x}g(t)dt-\int_{a}^{x}tg(t)dt$$

Then
$$f^{\prime}(x) =  \int_{a}^{x}g(t)dt+xg(x)-xg(x)=  \int_{a}^{x}g(t)dt$$
And finally
$$f^{\prime\prime}(x) = g(x).$$

Answer (score 1):

The full formula for differentiation under the intgeral sign is
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_{q(x)}^{p(x)} h(x,t) \,\mathrm{d}t = 
p'(x)h(x,p(x)) - q'(x)h(x,q(x)) + \int_{q(x)}^{p(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} h(x,t) \,\mathrm{d}t$$

Note that if the integrand was independent of $x$ then the last term would be zero and thus the derivative of the integral is just as you remember

However, here $(x-t)g(t)$ is not independent of $x$ which means that you have to consider the last term too
$$ \begin{align} 
f'(x)
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_a^x(x-t)g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \\
&= 1 \cdot (x-x)g(x) - 0 \cdot(x-a)g(a) + \int_a^x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} ((x-t)g(t)) \,\mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_a^x g(t) \,\mathrm{d}t \\
\implies f''(x) 
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_a^x g(t) \\
&= 1 \cdot g(x) - 0 \cdot g(a) + \int_a^x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(t) \,\mathrm{d}t \\
&= g(x) - 0 + \int_a^x 0 \,\mathrm{d}t \\
&= g(x)
\end{align} $$

and
$$\begin{align}
f(a) &= \int_a^a (x-t)g(t) \mathrm{d}t = 0 \\
f'(a) &= \int_a^a g(t) \mathrm{d}t = 0
\end{align}$$